# HTML5 canvas and php on Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

I would love to create a fiddle for this to show but i'm using php and it won't let me use php in those so i'm hoping someone will still know whats going on!

I have a javascript that works completely fine on it's own.  It is a HTML click and drag canvas.  The click and drag is constrained to a circle and draws the image to the canvas when you click a button that is next to the canvas.  This button calls a method that draws the image onto the canvas and makes it click and draggable.  I have tested this by itself and it works beautifully.  When I add a simple line of php code my click and drag canvas quits moving the image.  When you click the button to draw the image on, that works, but then you can't move the image.

I am beyond confused because the php that i am using has nothing to do with what is going on in the canvas.  Here is the code:

it's also important to point out that this code works fine in safari but doesn't work at all in chrome so i know it has something to do with chrome i just don't understand what the problem is.

My question is mainly, is there a way that safari loads versus chrome that would affect running javascript and php on the same page since it works fine in one browser and not the other.  I just added the code so people would know what I am referring to.

Here is the PHP

```
<dl class="header">
<?php
    $name = $_GET['id'];
    if ($name=="bracelet") {
       echo "<li>Design x!</li>";
    }
    elseif ($name=="purse") {
       echo "<li>Design y!</li>";
    }
    elseif ($name=="ring") {
       echo "<li>Design z!</li>";
    }
?>
</dl>
```

Here is the full code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style>
#canvas {
   border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<dl class="header">
<?php
    $name = $_GET['id'];
    if ($name=="bracelet") {
       echo "<li>Design x!</li>";
    }
    elseif ($name=="purse") {
       echo "<li>Design y!</li>";
    }
    elseif ($name=="ring") {
       echo "<li>Design z!</li>";
    }
?>
</dl>

<h5>Add Images and Canvases with the buttons<br>
Click to select which image to move.<br>
Then move the mouse to desired drop location<br>
and click again to drop the image there.</h5>

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<input type="image" src="http://s25.postimg.org/tovdg674b/crystal_003.png" id="button1" width="35"     height="20"></input>
<input type="image" src="http://s25.postimg.org/ph0l7f5or/crystal_004.png" id="button2" width="35" height="20"></input>
<input type="image" src="http://s25.postimg.org/60fvkwakr/crystal_005.png" id="button3" width="35" height="20"></input>
<input type="image" src="http://s25.postimg.org/fz5fl49e3/crystal_006.png" id="button4" width="35" height="20"></input>
<button id="save">save</button>
 <br>
<script>
// canvas stuff
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 50;

var contexts = [];
var points = [];

// image stuff
var states = [];
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {}
img.src = "http://s25.postimg.org/5qs46n4az/crystal_009.png";

setUpCanvas();
setUpPoints();

function setUpCanvas() {
   contexts.push(canvas.getContext("2d"));
   // link the new canvas to its context in the contexts[] array
   canvas.contextIndex = contexts.length;
   // wire up the click handler
   canvas.onclick = function (e) {
      handleClick(e, this.contextIndex);
   };
  // wire up the mousemove handler
  canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
      handleMousemove(e, this.contextIndex);
   };
   canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
                        removeState(this.contextIndex);
                        });
}

function setUpPoints() {
   //points that make up a circle circumference to an array
   points = [];
   for (var degree=0; degree<360; degree++) {
    var radians = degree * Math.PI/180;
    var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
    var xpoint = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians);
    var ypoint = centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians);
    points.push({
                x: xpoint,
                y: ypoint
                });
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0].x + 4, points[0].y + 4)
//draws the thin line on the canvas
for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pt = points[i];
    ctx.lineTo(pt.x + 4, pt.y + 4);
}
ctx.stroke(); //end of drawing the thin line
}

function addCircle() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(points[0].x + 4, points[0].y + 4)
   //draws the thin line on the canvas
   for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pt = points[i];
    ctx.lineTo(pt.x + 4, pt.y + 4);
  }
   ctx.stroke(); //end of drawing the thin line
 }

function clearAll() {
   //Clear all canvases
   for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
      var context = contexts[i];
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  } 
}

function handleClick(e, contextIndex) {

    e.stopPropagation();

   var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
   var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);

   for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

      var state = states[i];
      console.log(state);

    if (state.dragging) {
        state.dragging = false;
        state.draw();
        continue;
    }
    if (state.contextIndex == contextIndex && mouseX > state.x && mouseX < state.x + state.width && mouseY > state.y && mouseY < state.y + state.height) {
        state.dragging = true;
        state.offsetX = mouseX - state.x;
        state.offsetY = mouseY - state.y;
        state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
    }
    state.draw();
  }
}

function handleMousemove(e, contextIndex) {
   e.stopPropagation();

   var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
   var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);
   clearAll();
   addCircle();
   var minDistance = 1000;
   var minPoint = -1;

   for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

    var state = states[i];

    if (state.dragging) {
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var pt = points[i];
            var dx = mouseX - pt.x;
            var dy = mouseY - pt.y;
            if ((dx > 0 && dx>120)) {
                state.x = mouseX - state.offsetX;
                state.y = mouseY - state.offsetY;
                state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
            } else if ((dx < 0 && dx < -120)) {
                state.x = mouseX - state.offsetX;
                state.y = mouseY - state.offsetY;
                state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
            }
            else {
                var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                if (distance < minDistance) {
                    minDistance = distance;
                    //points in relation to the constrained line (where it will be drawn to)
                    //reset state.x and state.y to closest point on the line
                    state.x = pt.x - img.width / 2;
                    state.y = pt.y - img.height / 2;
                    state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    state.draw();
   }
}

function removeState(contextIndex) {
   for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

    var state = states[i];
    state.remove();
   }
}

function addState(image) {
   var ptxy = points[1];
   state = {}
   state.dragging = false;
   state.contextIndex = 1;
   state.image = image;
   state.x = ptxy.x - image.width / 2;
   state.y = ptxy.y - image.height / 2;
   state.width = image.width;
   state.height = image.height;
   state.offsetX = 0;
   state.offsetY = 0;
   state.draw = function () {
    var context = contexts[this.contextIndex - 1];
    if (this.dragging) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width + 2, this.height + 2)
    }
    context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
}
state.draw();
return (state);
}
function save() {
   // var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

$("#button1").click(function () {
                states.push(addState(img));
                });
$("#button2").click(function () {
                states.push(addState(img));
                });
$("#button3").click(function () {
                states.push(addState(img));
                });
$("#button4").click(function () {
                states.push(addState(img));
                });
$("#save").click(function () {
             save();
             });


</script> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: so we should read through that wall of code and try to GUESS where/what your "line of php" is?

Comment: its the one at the top that says <?php

Comment: Well I revised it and added it as a separate block.  I also revised what my question is mostly.  I added the code incase someone wanted to see it but I mainly want to know if there is a reason that php and click and drag would work in safari but not work on chrome.

Comment: I added a `<!doctype html>` declaration to the start of your code and tried it in Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.120 m (64-bit)).A couple of observations - regardless of which gem you choose, a different one is placed on the canvas. You cant click and drag, but _can_ click to select, followed by moving it - though this doesn't always work. I also note that `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.map` responds with a 404 - no idea if that's a (the?) deal-breaker though.

Comment: Yea thats what i meant sorry click to select and then drag.  And the 404 is weird it says not found but then runs the jquery just fine (it can't run with out that so that is weird) but anyways it was working just fine with that happening.  I'm so confused why everything works in safari and then not in Chrome I literally don't know what could be the problem.  If you strip away all the php it works just fine in Chrome, but the php shouldn't affect anything as it is used to display text...which makes me even more confused.

Comment: @ShawnaMacNabb - no drama. Can't see any problem with it here. I get the expected php message if I don't add "?id=bracelet" to the url. However, I don't observe any difference with the php present or removed. Sorry!

Comment: Well now if only it would work on my browser!  What the heck!

Comment: Ha I figured it out, it was a dumb mistake, as usual with programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone curious and wanting to know the answer of how i solved this here you go.  I am new to HTML5 canvas and how it works.  After a lot of trial and error I found out that the canvas offset was wrong once the canvas changed from the top of the screen to somewhere else.  It was as simple as that....